# isolating mongo operations in tests

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using the following code in a Ruby application (using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/)) to roll the database back between test cases:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DB.transaction(:rollback=>:always, :auto_savepoint=>true){example.run}
  end
end
```

I'd love to  have something similar in my Mongo tests, but I have only been able to find a [manual process](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#phase-commits-rollback) that requires a lot of specific information about the data I want to rollback. I'd like something more generic, similar to the ruby snippet above, that would just restore the DB to the state previous to each test block.

E.g.:

```
// psuedocode
var db = mongoose.connect('test-db');

afterEach(function () {
  db.rollback();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2018, Mongo 4 and Mongoose 5.2 support transactions

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not support transactions (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/). If you want to use transactions, you'll have to use a different database.  Most SQL databases support transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jeremy. I probably shouldn't have used the word "transactions" in my title. I'm not necessarily looking for transaction support but rather a mongo solution that achieves what a rollback does in sequel (however hacky). I'm going to edit the title to "operations" to make things clearer. Please let me know if there's a better way I can word things.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you call them operations or transactions, MongoDB doesn't support the concept of rolling back changes automatically.  You'll have to use a manual process to do so.